# SQLite date - find event from today

Tags: android, sqlite

I would like to retrieve from a SQLite database a list of events which have their `start_time` "today". `start_time` contains a timestamp e.g. like this `1338613200000`.

I tried this:

`SELECT * FROM events WHERE date(start_time, 'unixepoch')=date('now')`

Doesn't work...

I achieved the same thing in MySQL with such a statement:

`SELECT * FROM events WHERE DATE(start_time)=CURDATE();`

**EDIT:**
It's the problem with my timestamps. They have three zeros too much

Comment: Now I can see, that my timestamp is a few zeros too long... Which appears to be the problem. My first attempt was right, just the timestamps were wrong. Anyway, I hope this statement will help someone at least

Comment: CURDATE() will give you just date and not the time.And i think here your start_time value has date+time(YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS) so the comparison will differ bcoz just the date matches and the time doesnt.

Comment: The MySQL statement works, because DATE() also gives only date (just as CURDATE(). But let's not get offtopic:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java uses milliseconds since the Unix epoch, whereas I'm guessing SQLite uses seconds.

Divide System.currentTimeMillis() by 1000 before querying the database.

Comment: Now that you wrote it, it seems so obvious... I was really sleepy yesterday

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM events 
WHERE datetime(start_time,'unixepoch', 'localtime')
BETWEEN DATE('now') AND DATE('now', '+1 day')
```

See more details in [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: I used these docs. I'll try your solution immediately. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
long l=c.getTimeInMillis();
```

and do something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE start_time=l;
```

see if that works.

Comment: Nope. There's no such function as NOW() in sqlite

Comment: sorry i was thinking in terms of MySql.I have edited my answer pls check if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your help, see the comment above, this is why I have problems. Somewhere upon the insertion some zeros get added to my timestamp and it's in some 44800 year... My first method works with correct timestamp and I'm sure yours would work too

Comment: This will only match events that occur on the exact same second.